# How to transfer files from Azure Data Lake to Network File Folder(Remote server folder) using Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake, file-format

Is it possible to transfer files from Azure Data Lake to remote file server using Azure Data Factory. I don't have any problem with source but i am not sure how i can achieve for destination.

Am I able to transfer files from ADL to local file folder but I am unsure about how we can do this with remote server.

Help me if you have any idea on these.

Answer (score 0):

Per my knowledge, all the transmissions in ADF are hosted on the [Integration Runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-integration-runtime). So i suppose that there are 2 conditions in this scenario:

1.Your remote server is hosted in the public network, [Default IR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-integration-runtime#azure-integration-runtime) should be used. You could consider to expose REST API of your remote file server and try to configure it as sink dataset in the copy activity.

2.Your remote server is hosted in private network, then [Self-Hosted IR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-integration-runtime#self-hosted-integration-runtime) should be used and you have to install Self-Hosted IR. However, currently, MS only supports running the self-hosted IR on a Windows operating system according to the official [statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-integration-runtime#self-hosted-ir-compute-resource-and-scaling).

Comment: Thanks @Jay Gong for the update , its really helpful. My server would be the Private network and it will be on windows OS only. So do u mean by option 2 , i need to install the IR in that server  machine and provide the host details as file location and user and name password as server credentials ? . Can you please elaborate on how can i achieve it on this environment.